# How do I access nginx https externally because it seems to be being blocked?

Tags: nginx, https, amazon-lightsail

I've setup a lightsail Ubuntu 18.04 instance, opened port 443 through the Lightsail console and attached a static IP which is correctly mapped to www.budgetweapon.com. However, I can't connect externally. What am I missing?

I've checked to ensure port 443 is open through the lightsail console and I've checked that it is open externally by using an open port checker which says it's open but I still can't connect (get a connection timeout). I also confirmed that I was able to curl the https endpoint when actually on the server and I got back the expected html so nginx is definitely working. I also just tried running a SimpleHttpServer through Python on port 80 and I was able to connect successfully as well using http://www.budgetweapon.com. 
Here's the nginx conf and the docker-compose.yml file respectively.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name budgetweapon.com www.budgetweapon.com;

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
          allow all;
          root /var/www/html;
        }

    location / {
           rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }
}
server 
{
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name budgetweapon.com www.budgetweapon.com;

        server_tokens off;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/budgetweapon.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/budgetweapon.com/privkey.pem;

        ssl_buffer_size 8k;

        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
        ssl_session_tickets off;

        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        location / {
            try_files $uri @nodejs;
        }

        location @nodejs {
                proxy_pass http://nodejs:8080;
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
                add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
                add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
                add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
                add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
                # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
                # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications
        }

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
}
```

```
version: '3'

services:
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: nodejs
    container_name: nodejs
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-network

  webserver:
    image: nginx:mainline-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - web-root:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
      - dhparam:/etc/ssl/certs
    depends_on:
      - nodejs
    networks:
      - app-network

volumes:
  certbot-etc:
  certbot-var:
  web-root:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /home/ubuntu/node_project/views/
      o: bind
  dhparam:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /home/ubuntu/node_project/dhparam/
      o: bind

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm completely stumped and I swear this worked properly earlier today

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that it was all working as when I switched to private mode in safari on my phone I was able to browse to the site and also from a work machine as well (although our proxy appears to intercept the connection and "wrap" the certificate from my machine with it's own certificate to make it seem secure). It appears to be a problem with my home PC which is blocking the https connection to the site because it thinks the certificate is dodgy - it's a staging certificate from Let's Encrypt so maybe this is why Chrome has decided to block it for me against my will